# Adding a condition to this array

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript code. The code grabs the text from all containers with a "selected-text" class and adds them to the textarea field of a form.

It works great, however, I need to add a condition so that it will ONLY add the text to the textarea field if the value is NOT equal to "none".

```
var selectionList = document.querySelectorAll(".selected-text");
myFormItems.value = [...selectionList].map(el=>el.textContent).join('\n');
```

My condition will be something like this:

```
if (selectionList.textContent != 'None') {
// do something
}
```

I know my condition above is not correct. The problem is that I know how to add a condition to a loop, but this is an array and I don't know how to properly do it or where exactly to put the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the filter function to remove data you don't want in a array:

```
var selectionList = document.querySelectorAll(".selected-text");
myFormItems.value = [...selectionList].map(el=>el.textContent).filter(txt=>txt !== 'None').join('\n');
```